# Azure CRON Sceduling

Tags: azure, cron, azure-logic-apps

I have one Azure function that need to execute on multiple (n) dynamically configured CRON schedules with different sets of parameters. For example, Function1 needs to execute on the first of the month with parameter X=1. Function1 needs to also run quarterly at 5 pm Friday with X=2, etc... The schedules is perfect for CRON Strings. The schedules and parameters are configurable in an app as are the numbers scheduled instances. Scheduler  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/scheduler/ has been deprecated so I can’t use that. Logic apps do not use CRON. is there an approach someone can suggest? So far all I have is one function that polls the various configurations, evaluates the CRON strings and kicks off Function1 as appropriate. I wanted to avoid polling.

Comment: azure function with time trigger hasn't been deprecated. Where you saw it?

Comment: I don't get it. Is it *impossible* for you to create more than one function? Otherwise it's just a matter of configure each function with diff cron schedules.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement is with azure function timer trigger and do not need to use azure scheduler.

Azure function timer trigger also run with cron expression, you can refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-scheduled-function) to know how to create a function with timer trigger. And this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=csharp) will help you know about the cron expression in azure function timer trigger.

By the way, azure function timer trigger can just schedule one cron expression, so if you want your function to execute on multiple cron expression, you need to create multiple azure functions with different cron expression.

**Update:**

Create multiple timer trigger functions with different cron expression, show as below example.

One function with its cron expression and with the X = 1.
[image]
[image]

Another function with its cron expression and with the X = 2.
[image]
[image]

You can create n timer trigger functions in your function app(with different cron expressions and different parameter(X) in it). **And when you create this function app, you can choose "[Consumption plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#consumption-plan)" for it, then you do not need to worry about how many functions in this function app and do not worry about resource management. You just need to pay for the time that your code runs.**

[image]

Comment: And that is the problem, I have one function with n CRON triggers and parameters.

Comment: Hi @jlo-gmail I provide some more details of azure timer trigger function, please check the "update" in my answer. Does it match your requirements ?

Comment: Hi @jlo-gmail, may I know if your problem was solved. If the solution helps your problem, could you please mark my answer as "accepted", thanks~

Comment: I was aware of the information listed, please re-read my problem(I clarified it some) I have ONE function to be run on multiple, dynamically determined CRON schedule. I had hoped to avoid polling,